CORS Issue with Nginx and Express Server for React App in QA Environment
I am encountering a persistent CORS issue in my QA environment setup. My configuration includes the following components:

Frontend: React app hosted on an EC2 instance, served via Nginx.
Backend: Node.js Express API running on the same EC2 instance, proxied by Nginx.
CORS Configuration: Handled within the Express server, but I'm receiving CORS errors during OPTIONS requests when calling the API from localhost:3000 for local development.

The error seen in the browser console is:
Request URL: https://qa.example.com/auth/login
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Not Allowed

Nginx Configuration
worker_processes auto;
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # HTTP to HTTPS redirection
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name qa.example.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    # HTTPS server block
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name qa.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/qa.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/qa.example.com/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        # Serve React frontend
        root /home/ec2-user/build;
        index index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        # Proxy requests to backend API
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

Express Server (server.js)
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import http from 'http';
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';
import connectDB from './config/db.js';
import authMiddleware from './middlewares/authMiddleware.js';
import authRoutes from './routes/authRoutes.js';
// Other imports omitted for brevity

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

// Allowed origins for CORS
const allowedOrigins = [
  'http://localhost:3000',  // Local development
  'https://qa.example.com', // QA environment
  'https://example.com',    // Production environment
];

// CORS options
const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if (!origin || allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  },
  credentials: true,
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
};

// Apply CORS
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Preflight handling for OPTIONS requests
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));

// Middleware to parse JSON
app.use(express.json());

// MongoDB connection
connectDB();

// Define routes
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
// Other routes omitted for brevity

// Create HTTP server
const server = http.createServer(app);

// WebSocket server initialization
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ server });
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('WebSocket connected');
});

// Start server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

Things I've Tried:

CORS Handling in Node.js: Allowed origins include localhost:3000 for local development, qa.example.com for QA, and example.com for production.
Preflight Handling: The Express server is configured to handle OPTIONS requests.
Nginx Proxy Configuration: I have set up Nginx to proxy requests to
the backend API (/api).
Nginx Headers: Added the necessary CORS headers at the API level in Nginx.

Question:
Despite configuring CORS properly in the Express server and setting up Nginx as a reverse proxy, I still receive a 405 status code for OPTIONS requests. Is there something I might be missing or a better approach to resolving this issue?

The CORS issue you're facing seems to stem from potential configuration problems related to the handling of preflight requests (OPTIONS) in both your Express application and Nginx setup. But that's just a well educated guess based on my own experiences.
Review Browser Caching: Sometimes browsers cache CORS preflight results. To ensure you're testing with fresh headers, clear your browser cache or try the requests in a private/incognito window.
Double-check the headers you are allowing in your CORS configuration: The allowedHeaders in your Express CORS options include 'Content-Type' and 'Authorization'. If your frontend sends any other headers, you need to add those to the allowed list. For example, if you’re sending an X-Requested-With header, include that as well.
Verify Express Server is Listening to OPTIONS: If you have already set up your Express server to handle OPTIONS requests using app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));, make sure the endpoint you are testing (/auth/login) is covered by your CORS configuration as well.
Test CORS with CURL: You can test your API endpoint directly using curl:
curl -X OPTIONS https://qa.example.com/auth/page -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000" -i

This command will show you the response headers returned by your server for the OPTIONS request.
Problem solved?
